# Отслеживание появления новых материалов C#

Tags: c#, парсер

Здравствуйте. Как можно корректно отслеживать появление новых материалов на определенном сайте? Сейчас у меня обычное приложение, в котором на сайт отправляется запрос каждые несколько минут (с помощью таймера) и получается список материалов главной страницы, а затем сравнивается с тем, что уже есть и материалы, которых нет, выводятся в соответствующем поле. Только вот я понимаю, что такими темпами скоро могу и бан словить, особенно если запросы слишком часто будут отправляться.
Поэтому подумал, что, может быть, есть какой-нибудь нормальный способ отслеживания появления материалов?
у сайта есть rss.

Comment: Если `у сайта есть rss.` почему бы его и не использовать?

Comment: Более того в .NET Framework есть [инструмент для работы с rss из коробки...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx)

Comment: Можете подсказать как вообще с rss работать?

Comment: Хорошо, это понял. А вот по поводу запросов: их, получается, все также отправлять с помощью таймера? Или есть какой-то способ, который на автомате сам будет получать обновления?

Comment: Это зависит от того куда вы запрос делаете. Может быть у сайта есть просто API для взаимодействия с ним. Можете проверять на наличие обновлений методом `HEAD` и смотреть на заголовок `Last-Modified`. Или смотреть stauts code (304 Not Modified). Так же бывает что фид отправляет в теле дополнительный параметр `GUID` или специальный токен или id фида или время создания - по которым можно легко понять есть ли там новые элементы или нет. Делать запрос в таком случае Вам придется в цикле/таймере.

Comment: Апи точно нет. А за слишком частое кол-во запросов к rss бан получить можно?)

Comment: Rss для того и придуман что бы постоянно получать актуальную информацию. Конечно если Вы из одного IP делаете каждую секунду запрос - то скорее всего получите бан. А если `на сайт отправляется запрос каждые несколько минут` - то думаю проблем не будет. Опять же зависит от сайта, если это "действительно" проблема, напишите в суппорт сайта и спросите конкретную информацию у разработчиков.

Comment: Удалось получить содержимое главной страницы. Но в идеале хотелось бы еще добраться до 2 и 3 страницы. Это возможно? Я перехожу по адресу site.ru/rss.xml, но там отображается лишь 15 материалов, которые есть на главной странице...

Comment: ну тут смотрите сами. Если они поддерживают постраничную навигацию можете к запросу добавить параметр `site.ru/rss.xml?page=2` или может `site.ru/rss.xml/02/`

Comment: Вариант с ?page=2 ошибку не выдал, но в ответ я получил те же самые записи, что и на главной странице.